# My hardrive is giving constantly Read-Only system error. How do I fixe this?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive

When I plug in the Harddrive for a minute or less it`s working good. I can copy stuff, create files, etc. But sudently it the permissions just change and becomes read-only hard-drive. I already foundo how to change this permissions (also with commandos). However, even when I change after some seconds everithing comes back to the read only... What can I do.

Comment: Have you read the logs as to why it's *flipping* from RW to RO?   Whatever your logs say - that is what you should investigate; but as we don't know your OS/product/release details; we're guessing.  See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: hi @ guiverc, installing smart mono tools is not an option for now. he says it's constantly at read only mode.

Comment: You boot *live* media so the drive is not being used & perform checks from there, not the installed/problematic OS....   Reading the logs is done before reboot (due to *fs flipping RO* the logs won't be written to disk...) but exploration on health of drives is done from *live* media so drives aren't used (SMART is read from electronics & you can plan if remaining health of a *dying* drive is kept for getting any data off it that is required - not during exploration or decision making... you avoid using a *dying* or *unhealthy* drive until you've planned what you'll do  @RishonJR

Comment: so what can I do?

Comment: @guiverc So you mention that. you hadn't mentioned In the initial comment.

Comment: No OS/product/release details were given, we have no idea if it's a raspberry pi using SD card (no SMART exists) a *s390x* system, or more common *amd64* box with SMART drive, thus my comment was rather *vague* intentionally so it applied to all @RishonJR

Answer (score 2):

The hard drive is failing, the most common cause of this kind of action. Replace the hard drive its done.

Comment: what about formatating it?

Comment: Formatting won't recover a dying HD.

Comment: try replacing the hard drive with a new ssd.